# create_session doesn't set SET-COOKIE header

Tags: session-cookies, phoenix-framework, setcookie

i was under the assumption that `create_session` if the endpoint.ex was configured to use the cookie store, would set the `SET-COOKIE` response header

```
  # The session will be stored in the cookie and signed,
  # this means its contents can be read but not tampered with.
  # Set :encryption_salt if you would also like to encrypt it.
  plug Plug.Session,
    log: :debug,
    store: :cookie,
    key: "some_key",
    signing_salt: "some_salt"
```

this is my authentication controller ( just a part of it)

```
  def callback(%{ assigns: %{ ueberauth_auth: auth } } = conn, params) do
    params = build_params(auth)
    user = find_or_create_user params
    conn = put_session(conn, :current_user, user)
    IO.inspect conn.resp_headers
    IO.inspect get_session(conn, :current_user)
    render conn, "index.html"
    #Helpers.redirect!(conn, "/")
  end

  def build_params(auth) do
    %{email: auth.info.email, github_token: auth.credentials.token, github_user: auth.info.nickname}
  end

  def find_or_create_user(params) do
    case DBRepo.get_by(User, email: params.email) do
        nil ->
          User.changeset(%User{}, params)
          |> DBRepo.insert
        results ->
          results
    end
  end
```

> IO.inspect conn.resp_headers

returns

```
[{"cache-control", "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"},  {"x-request-id", "vh8l2deodne1k2iloa4c3e4qdpmh857n"},  {"x-frame-options", "SAMEORIGIN"}, {"x-xss-protection", "1; mode=block"},  {"x-content-type-options", "nosniff"}]
```

> ```
> IO.inspect get_session(conn, :current_user)
> ```
>
> returns the user as expected

Comment: Where is `create_session` defined? It must be returning a conn in which case you should assign it back (`conn = case find_user(...) do ... end`) because Elixir structs are immutable.

Comment: Does the cookie exist in the actual response sent to the browser? Plug.Session sets the actual session cookie just before the response is actually sent (using `register_before_send`) so it won't appear in `conn.resp_headers`, but it should be there if you make a real request.

Comment: ok i figured it out, i couldn't see the cookie because it was httpOnly:true thanks for the help.

do you want to make an answer with all this information and ill mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see the session cookie in `resp_headers` because `Plug.Session` sets that cookie [just before the response is actually sent, using `Plug.Conn.register_before_send`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/8cb5b6881fd3e4dc2b62a2a978283164a7369966/lib/plug/session.ex#L85-L112). If you make a request using any HTTP client (browser, `curl`, etc), you'll see the `Set-Cookie` header.

```
defmodule MyApp.PageController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> put_session(:foo, :bar)
    |> text("")
  end
end
```

```
$ curl -I localhost:4000
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
server: Cowboy
date: Mon, 20 Feb 2017 08:57:36 GMT
content-length: 0
set-cookie: _my_app_key=SFMyNTY.g3QAAAABbQAAAANmb29kAANiYXI.F0G6lsgPxsYjq97tonLy1gRkOBUVcfwqKZdozgGRG-c; path=/; HttpOnly
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
x-request-id: uoplksup9ndakf5sdr5shpjsjhvu849v
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
```

Comment: and by default phoenix adds the `httpOnly: true` flag so you wont see it in document.cookies